# Sum of Counts between two dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two CSV files. First file contains Machine Id, Date and TestCount.

[image]

Second file contains Machine Id, Part Id and Close Date.

[image]

I need to fetch the date range (based on cell value C2 & C3 for 1st instance, C3 & C4 for next instance so on) from second file and calculate the sum of TestCount in the first file for every Id. The Sum of count is specific to every Part ID.

Below is the expected result.

[image]

I have tried below code but it works when there is only one file. How do I take the input from 2nd file w.r.t Machine ID, Part ID and get the sum of TestCount for each Machine ID and Part ID?

```
import pandas as pd
        
data1 = {'Machine ID': ['111','111','111','111','111','111','111','222','222','222','222','333','333','333'],
             'Date': ['2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03','2023-01-15','2023-01-16','2023-02-28','2023-03-03','2023-02-03','2023-02-04','2023-02-05','2023-02-06','2023-01-10','2023-01-15','2023-01-25'],
             'TestCount':[200,15,150,40,35,50,175,70,56,240,200,150,230,220]}

data2 = {'Machine ID': ['111','111','111','111','111','222','222','333','333'],
        'Part ID':['A1111','A1111','A1111','A1112','A1112','B2222','B2222','C3333','C3333'],
        'Close Date':['2023-01-01','2023-02-28','2023-03-31','2023-01-15','2023-03-15','2023-01-01','2023-02-20','2023-01-10','2023-03-10']}

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df1 = df1[(df1['Date'] >= '2023-01-01') & (df1['Date'] <= '2023-07-31')]

result1 = df1.groupby('Machine ID')['TestCount'].agg(['sum'])

merged_df = df1.merge(result1, on='Machine ID', suffixes=('', '_total'))

print(merged_df)


# output_data = {'Machine ID': ['111','111','111','111','111','222','222','333','333'],
#                'Part ID':['A1111','A1111','A1111','A1112','A1112','B2222','B2222','C3333','C3333'],
#                'Close Date':['2023-01-01','2023-02-28','2023-03-31','2023-01-15','2023-03-15','2023-01-01','2023-02-20','2023-01-10','2023-03-10'],
#                'sum':['NAN',490,175,'NAN',300,'NAN',566,'NAN',600]}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put the input dataframes and expected result as text? So we can copy-paste it?

Comment: Have edited the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `apply`:

```
df2["Start"] = df2["Close Date"].shift()
df2["Sum"] = df2.apply(lambda row: df1.loc[(df1["Date"].between(row["Start"],row["Close Date"]))&
                                           (df1["Machine ID"].eq(row["Machine ID"])),"TestCount"]
                       .sum(),
                       axis=1)
output = df2.drop(columns="Start")

>>> output
  Machine ID Part ID Close Date  Sum
0        111   A1111 2023-01-01    0
1        111   A1111 2023-02-28  490
2        111   A1111 2023-03-31  225
3        111   A1112 2023-01-15    0
4        111   A1112 2023-03-15  300
5        222   B2222 2023-01-01    0
6        222   B2222 2023-02-20  566
7        333   C3333 2023-01-10    0
8        333   C3333 2023-03-10  600
```

Comment: You should use a `groupby.shift` ;)

Comment: Yes, I used df2["Start"] = df2.groupby(['Machine ID','Part ID'])["Close Date"].shift()

Answer (score 2):

You can try (note: for row 2 the sum should be `225` - the dates are `2023-02-28` and `2023-02-28`, so `50 + 175`):

```py
def get_sum(g, dates):
    first, last = dates.iat[-2], dates.iat[-1]
    first, last = pd.to_datetime(first, unit="s"), pd.to_datetime(last, unit="s")
    machine_id = g["Machine ID"].iat[0]
    return df1.loc[(machine_id, slice(first, last)), "TestCount"].sum()


df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df2["Close Date - timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Close Date"]).map(
    pd.Timestamp.timestamp
)
df1 = df1.set_index(["Machine ID", "Date"])

out = []
for _, g in df2.groupby(["Machine ID", "Part ID"]):
    out.extend(
        g.rolling(2)["Close Date - timestamp"].apply(lambda dates: get_sum(g, dates))
    )

df2["Sum"] = out
df2 = df2.drop(columns="Close Date - timestamp")
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
  Machine ID Part ID  Close Date    Sum
0        111   A1111  2023-01-01    NaN
1        111   A1111  2023-02-28  490.0
2        111   A1111  2023-03-31  225.0
3        111   A1112  2023-01-15    NaN
4        111   A1112  2023-03-15  300.0
5        222   B2222  2023-01-01    NaN
6        222   B2222  2023-02-20  566.0
7        333   C3333  2023-01-10    NaN
8        333   C3333  2023-03-10  600.0
```